# Does 'new Image()' allow for use of cache (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, caching

If I use `new Image()` to load up an image in JavaScript, will it use a cached version if possible, or will it always load up a fresh copy?

```
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = 'http://...';
imgObj.onload = function (loadedImg) { }
```

Comment: I would setup the `onload` prior though. IIRC there are some strange Opera quirks with at least `onerror` and posting events synchronously vs. async. My memory fails though.

Comment: If you don't want to have it cached, add some random parameters to the source value, like: `'image.jpg?random=' + new Date().getTime()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'll load from cache if it's there, the same way a `<img>` in your markup would.

Comment: (Or perhaps not load from cache-- those pesky misconfigured servers!)

Comment: Well, he is close to century of bronze medals.

Answer (score 8):

One thing to note is that if you want `onload` to always happen (even when it's in cache) you should define **`onload` before `src`**.

```
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.onload = function (loadedImg) { }
imgObj.src = 'http://...';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force a reload by adding a bogus query string argument. If your statement assigning a URL to the src property of the image is

```
imgObj.src = 'http://www.mySite.com/images/anImage.png';
```

you could render it as

```
imgObj.src = 'http://www.mySite.com/images/anImage.png?foo=0';
```

Just understand that on subsequent loads it will still use the cached copy unless you change the query string argument.